# how do i refactor these 2 methods?

Tags: c#, refactoring

```
    public static void outputDetail(DateTime previousTime, ref double[] array, StreamWriter streamWriter)  //the parameter in here is not necessary, but want to maintain a similiarity in the TimeOfDay class
    {
        string outputString = previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Boolean bypass = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            outputString = outputString + "," + array[i].ToString();

            if (array[i] != 0)
                bypass = false;
        }
        if (bypass == false)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }


    public static void outputDetail(DateTime previousTime, ref int[] array, StreamWriter streamWriter)  //the parameter in here is not necessary, but want to maintain a similiarity in the TimeOfDay class
    {
        string outputString = previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Boolean bypass = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length -1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
            {
                outputString = outputString + "," + array[i].ToString();
                bypass = false;
            }
            else
            {
                outputString = outputString + ",";
            }
        }
        if (bypass == false)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

they are exactly the same, only one takes a double array and one takes an int array, i see some example use Iconvertible but i cant get the syntax right. can someone post some workable snippet for the method pls?

can how do i call it?

EDIT: thanks very much for the answer, i have another somewhat more complicated case i need to refactor, and the suggestion in here dont work on that 2 methods. Please click this link for more detail

[How do I refactor these 2 methods? Part 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620374/how-do-i-refactor-these-2-method-part-2)

Comment: You could use the 'fairly new' dynamic keyword for this instead of the type, personally not a big fan of it, but it is a possibility.

Comment: Yep, I'd use dynamic as well. It's a pain that numbers don't have any common root, but passing the second argument as array of dynamic elements would do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    public static void outputDetail<T>(DateTime previousTime, ref T[] array, System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter)  //the parameter in here is not necessary, but want to maintain a similiarity in the TimeOfDay class
    {
        string outputString = previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Boolean bypass = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!Object.Equals(array[i], default(T)))
            {
                outputString = outputString + "," + array[i].ToString();
                bypass = false;
            }
            else
            {
                outputString = outputString + ",";
            }
        }
        if (bypass == false)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);

        Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
```

What's changed?

First the method signature: it accepts a generic array of type `T` (so it doesn't matter if it's `int`, `double`, `bool` or `strings`).

Now you have to fix the comparison for zero. Zero is the default value for both int and double so you can use default(T) to get the default value for actual type and `Object.Equals()` for comparison (`==` and `!=` operators aren't defined for generic types).

Finally you just have to clear the array (again with zero) so you can simply use `Array.Clear()` to do all the job (and it's even little bit faster than a handmade `for`).

Comment: Even better than dynamic, because it works in compile time ;-) Although, it only works because the comparison is with 0. If we'd like to check if(array[i] == 1), then it would not do.

Comment: @xavier yes, it's really limited to this case (but to compare with something else you can use IConvertible). As alternative you may get the value to compare as parameter.

Comment: i know it is a stupid question, but how do i call the outputDetail<T> from my main?

Comment: @ClaytonLeung if your array is strongly typed then you do not have to change anything in your code. C# compiler will do everything for you: outputDetail(myTime, ref myArray, myStream)

Comment: thanks, i just found out :)))

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct, use generic is the best, in here I just re-factor you code a little bit using Linq for cleaner:

```
public static void outputDetail<T>(DateTime previousTime, ref T[] array, 
                                   StreamWriter streamWriter) where T : struct
{
    if (array.Any(a => !a.Equals(default(T))))
    {
        string outputString = string.Join(",", 
                                          previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                                          string.Join(",", array));

        streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);
    }

    array = Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), array.Length).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. By the way, concatenating strings like that is a burden on the GC, have a look at the StringBuilder class.

```
    public static void outputDetail<T>(DateTime previousTime, ref T[] array, StreamWriter streamWriter)  //the parameter in here is not necessary, but want to maintain a similiarity in the TimeOfDay class
    {
        var outputString = new StringBuilder(previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
        Boolean bypass = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            outputString.Append("," + array[i]);

            if (!(array[i].Equals(default(T))))
                bypass = false;
        }
        if (bypass == false)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = default(T);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative thought, as in Java, you could create an abstract class named Number which Integer, Doubles, etc. inherit from this abstract class. Then you could substitute the array for a Number Array. This is scalable and you can mix types.

This example is for Java, but gives the idea. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/185870/one-method-for-stack-of-either-integer-or-double-parameters

```
public abstract class Number
{
}



public static void outputDetail(DateTime previousTime, ref Number[] array, StreamWriter streamWriter)  //the parameter in here is not necessary, but want to maintain a similiarity in the TimeOfDay class
{
    string outputString = previousTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Boolean bypass = true;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        outputString = outputString + "," + array[i].ToString();

        if (array[i] != 0)
            bypass = false;
    }
    if (bypass == false)
        streamWriter.WriteLine(outputString);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here's an interesting discussion on the topic. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/261696-a-abstract-number-class/