# How do I refactor these 2 methods? Part 2.

Tags: c#, refactoring

This is the part 2 of my refactor problem. I have successfully refactor my previous method in here:

[how do i refactor these 2 methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618899/how-do-i-refactor-these-2-methods)

The second part is similar, however I am unable to successfully refactor this 2 methods. When using a generic method, I was stuck at the line:

```
temp = (T)Convert.ToInt(value);
```

So somehow I need a different approach to refactor these 2 methods.

```
public static void readDataDouble(string value, ref double[][] data, ref DateTime[] timeframe, ref DateTime[] date)
{

    string inputFile = "D:\\temp.csv";
    string[][] temp = null;

    if (File.Exists(inputFile))
    {
        string[] proRataVolumeFile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
        temp = new string[proRataVolumeFile.Length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < proRataVolumeFile.Length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = proRataVolumeFile[i].Split(',');
        }
    }
    date = new DateTime[temp.Length - 1];
    timeframe = new DateTime[temp[0].Length - 1];
    data = new double[temp.Length - 1][];

    for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i - 1] = new double[temp[i].Length - 1];

        for (int j = 1; j < temp[i].Length; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i][j].Length > 0)
                data[i - 1][j - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(temp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        date[i - 1] = Convert.ToDateTime(temp[i][0]);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < temp[0].Length; j++)
    {
        timeframe[j - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[0][j]);
    }
}

public static void readDataInt(string value, ref int[][] data, ref DateTime[] timeframe, ref DateTime[] date)
{

    string inputFile = "D:\\temp.csv";
    string[][] temp = null;

    if (File.Exists(inputFile))
    {
        string[] proRataVolumeFile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
        temp = new string[proRataVolumeFile.Length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < proRataVolumeFile.Length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = proRataVolumeFile[i].Split(',');
        }
    }
           //convert the string to int

    date = new DateTime[temp.Length - 1];
    timeframe = new DateTime[temp[0].Length - 1];
    data = new int[temp.Length - 1][];

    for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i - 1] = new int[temp[i].Length - 1];

        for (int j = 1; j < temp[i].Length; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i][j].Length > 0)
                data[i - 1][j - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(temp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        date[i - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[i][0]);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < temp[0].Length; j++)
    {
        timeframe[j - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[0][j]);
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate if someone post some working snippet to this problem and how can i call it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the code that you are having problems getting to work in addition to the original methods that you are trying to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics again:

```
    public static void readDataInt<T>(string value, ref T[][] data, ref DateTime[] timeframe, ref DateTime[] date)
    {
        string inputFile = "D:\\temp.csv";
        string[][] temp = null;

        if (File.Exists(inputFile))
        {
            string[] proRataVolumeFile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
            temp = new string[proRataVolumeFile.Length][];

            for (int i = 0; i < proRataVolumeFile.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = proRataVolumeFile[i].Split(',');
            }
        }

        date = new DateTime[temp.Length - 1];
        timeframe = new DateTime[temp[0].Length - 1];
        data = new T[temp.Length - 1][];

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i - 1] = new T[temp[i].Length - 1];

            for (int j = 1; j < temp[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (temp[i][j].Length > 0)
                    data[i - 1][j - 1] = (T)((IConvertible)temp[i][j]).ToType(typeof(T),
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            date[i - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[i][0]);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < temp[0].Length; j++)
        {
            timeframe[j - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[0][j]);
        }
    }
```

Again you have to change strongly typed array to its generic counterpart, besides this the only notable change is the line where the conversion occurs. Because `string` implements `IConvertible` you can use `IConvertible.ToType()` method to convert it to any other (supported) type. Conversions to primitive types are supported, for less trivial conversions you may consider to use a conversion library like [Universal Type Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248440/Universal-Type-Converter). Please note that now the conversion needs an `IFormatProvider` (doubles, for example, are represented in different ways for different cultures).

Comment: You welcome, please note that if you want to use Converter class you can write this too:       data[i - 1][j - 1] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(temp[i][j], typeof(T),       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);